# Sard's Theorem For Constant functions

Tags: differential-geometry

It states:

Let $g:A \to R^n$ be continuously differentiable, where $A \subset R^n$ is open, and let $B=${${x \in A: \det g'(x)=0}$}.  Thne $g(B)$ has measure $0$.

Okay....  obviously this theorem is right... but why don't constant functions violate this?  After all, the  derivative of a constant function is $0$ EVERYWHERE.... so that can't possibly be measure zero!

Comment: Well, technically, it's hardly "obvious" that Sard's Theorem is true -- but yes, if you take the theorem on faith, then sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is $g(B)$, not $B$, that has measure $0$. If $g$ is constant, then g(B) contains a single point (the constant).

Comment: x)   
thanks... its obvious now.